# Implementing Reverse Sorted LinkedList

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a linked list sorted in reverse order in Java but the add method is giving me weird results.
I have to implement this list (can't just use `LinkedList`, which is what I would do in practice) and I must use recursion.

The array I'm inserting to test the code:

```
[-20, 0, -10, 5, 12, 1, -100, -50, -101, 200]
```

Heres's the relevant bit from SortedLinkedSet:

```
public boolean add(T el) {
if (firstNode == null || el.compareTo(firstNode.getValue()) > 0 ) {
    //the new element will become the new first node
    firstNode = new SortedLinkedSetNode<T>(el, firstNode);
    return true;
} else { 
    return firstNode.add(el);
}
}
```

Here's SortedLinkedSetNode:

```
public boolean add(T el) {


    //reduction steps
        if(el == null)
            return false;
        else if(contains(el))
            return false;
        else if(el.compareTo(this.getValue()) <= 0)
        {
            if(next == null)
            {
                next = new SortedLinkedSetNode<T>(el);
                return true;
            }

            return next.add(el);
        }
        else
        {
            //base case
            SortedLinkedSetNode<T> newNode = new SortedLinkedSetNode<T>(el);
            newNode.next = this.next;
            this.next = newNode;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The output:

```
[200, 12, 5, 0, 1, -20, -10, -100, -50, -101]
```

Moving the `if(next == null)` check into an `else if` block before `else if(el.compareTo(this.getValue()) <= 0)` gives the same results.

I've been unable to make heads or tails of these results for several hours :\

For testing, I've just been inspecting the list in memory.
Before anyone asks, this is indeed homework.  I'm not looking for handouts, just help.

Comment: did you override compareTO?

Comment: Why don't you just implement a "normally" sorted linked list and use "reverse comparators" instead?

Comment: @StinePike yes it returns the node value's compareTo (which is Integer.compareTo)

Comment: @fge could you explain in more detail?

Comment: (side question: "I must use..." <-- homework question?) What I mean is that it is easier to implement a normally sorted linked list; do that and at init time, create a `Comparator` which returns the "reverse" of what your elements' `Comparable` normally returns, and use that to insert

Comment: @fge A "normally sorted" linked-list implementation would be exactly the same as this one.

Comment: @fge This is a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base case isn't right. If `el` > `this.getValue()` you are still inserting it after the current node, which breaks your order invariant.

One thing you could do is insert a new node after the current, then change the new node's value to the current node's value and the current node's value to `el`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your suggestion vastly improves the ordering, but one Integer is still out of place for some reason.  The results: [200, 12, 5, 1, 0, -20, -10, -100, -50, -101]  Any idea why the -20 and -10 are switched?

Comment: The new base case is:       `SortedLinkedSetNode<T> newNode = new SortedLinkedSetNode<T>(getValue());  newNode.next = this.next;  this.next = newNode;  value = el;`

Comment: You might want to add some temporary debugging prints to show the actions your code is taking. What order are you inserting elements in?

Comment: edited the question with the array I'm inserting to test the code.  I just add them in a loop, starting with -20 and ending with 200.  Maybe it's significant that -20 is inserted first and is the one dodgy element?

Comment: (-100 and -50 are swapped, too.)

Comment: Your `if (next == null)` condition has the same issue your base case originally did. Imagine your list contains only [0, -20]. Now insert -10 and walk through the code in your head.

Comment: Changed the null case to be like the base case.  Hmm... the error occurs when inserting the [-100].  Before that, the list is [12, 5, 1, 0, -10, -20]